# React Hook "React.useState" is called in function "form" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React hook for state but when I use useState it show an error which is:

```
    Compiled with problems:X
    
    ERROR
    
    
    src\Form.js
      Line 9:29:  React Hook "React.useState" is called in function "form" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
    
    Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

The code that I used is:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
export default function form() {
  const changeValue = (event) => {};

  const [text, setName] = useState("enter here");
  return (
    <>
      <div className="my-3">
        <textarea className="form-control" placeholder="enter text here" rows="10"></textarea>
      </div>

      <button className="btn btn-success">Convert to upper case</button>
      <button className="btn btn-success">Convert to lower case</button>
      <button className="btn btn-danger">clear</button>
      <hr />
      <p>string have </p>
    </>
  );
}
```

I am unable to find the error, can anyone tell how I remove the error. The `package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "text-analyzer",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  }
```

Comment: Change `function form` to `function Form` as React expects component names to start with a capital letter.

Comment: The answer to your question is literally in the error message

Answer (score 2):

Your form() Name that component name change by other name
export default function form() {

}
Example

export default function Myform() {

}

Note : The component name should Start with UpperCase Letter

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It should be `Form` with a capital `F`. A React component should start with a capital letter. And if you are creating a custom hook, it should start with `use`, like `useData`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
export default function Form() {
  const changeValue = (event) => {};
  const [text, setName] = useState("enter here");

  return (
    <>
      <div className="my-3">
        <textarea className="form-control" placeholder="enter text here" rows="10"></textarea>
      </div>

      <button className="btn btn-success">Convert to upper case</button>
      <button className="btn btn-success">Convert to lower case</button>
      <button className="btn btn-danger">clear</button>
      <hr />
      <p>string have </p>
    </>
  );
}
```